# where to prevent default behaviour

Tags: javascript, events

In javascript when executing code following a user interaction ie.e click on a link

is it best to prevent the default behaviour (`event.preventDefault()`) before attempting to run your javascript code or after?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It depends what you're doing. But if you want to prevent the behaviour, then yes. The placement of `preventDefault()` depends what you're doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it when you know you want to.

You might not know that until other parts of the function have run—validating form input on *submit* would want to prevent the default action if the validation failed but not if it passed—so you certainly can't always do it at the top of the function.

Answer (score 0):

I always do something like this:

```
$("#selector").bind("click", function(e){  
  e.preventDefault();
  //DO THE REST OF THE THINGS
});
```

Mostly to prevent any unintended bubbling and make it immediately clear what's going on with my script.